# Spivak Chapter 14 Question 25 Part a

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

I'm stuck on the following problem from Spivak:
[image]

What I've done so far is to break this problem into 2 cases: where r is rational, and where r is irrational. In the case where r is rational, I was able to deduce, using derivative rules and the fundamental theorem of calculus, that the integral must converge to $-(r+1)^-$$^1$. However, I'm struggling to handle the case where r is an irrational number, because I'm not sure what x to the power of an irrational number means. Could I get a hint on how to approach this case? Or is the problem only asking us to prove this for rational numbers, especially considering that I don't think irrational powers have been defined yet (or maybe I'm missing something?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Spivak only defines the meaning of $a^x$ (when $a>0$ and $x\in\Bbb R$) four chapters later, and since he uses the letter $r$, I think that you can safely assume that $r\in\Bbb Q$.